# Complex Numbers - Sketching on Argand Diagram

Tags: complex-numbers

Sketch the subsets of the Argand diagram -

> Draw near labelled sketched to indicate each of the subsets of the Argand diagram described below.
>
> 1. $\{z: |z|\ge 1\text{ and }0\le\operatorname{Arg} z\le\frac\pi3\}$
> 2. $\{z:z+\bar z\gt 0\} $

I can solve Question 1 , but I am not sure about Question 2. Can someone please help.

[[Original scan](http://i43.tinypic.com/70j9dk.jpg)]

Comment: $z + \bar{z} \gt 0 \iff \frac{z + \bar{z}}{2} \gt 0 \iff Re(z) \gt 0$.  So it's the solid region to the right of the imaginary axis.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: There's is the full question.

Comment: @EnjoysMath does $Re(z) = 2*Re(z)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z + \bar z$ means you add up a complex number and its conjugate and the result must be higher than $0$.

Thus $(a + bi) + (a - bi) = 2a$. Sketch the graph $2*\hspace{2 pt}Re(z)$.

Comment: Thank you! Understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Big hint: $$z+\bar{z}=(a+bi)+(a-bi)=2a$$